# Angular masonry directive hides inner elements, error: ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, masonry

Trying to use the [Angular Masonry Directive](https://github.com/klederson/angular-masonry-directive) by klederson on a project, but having trouble getting it to work. The space is taken up in the body tag for the elements but they aren't visible, and the error mentioned above is displayed in the console.

Injecting the masonry dependancy:

```
angular.module("cardSite",['masonry'])
```

Markup I'm using to call masonry in. Whenever I try the JS way I get the same error.

```
    <div masonry='{ "transitionDuration" : "0.4s" , "itemSelector" : ".grid-item"}' class="grid">
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item--height2">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
        <div masonry-tile class="grid-item">...</div>
    </div>
```

Calling the script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="scripts/directives/angular-masonry-directive.js"></script>
```

URL of relevant page: 
http://marcmurray.net/test_sites/card_site/index.html

Image of error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzXnT.png

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/vzhUUtKtrZWxCwMITOL6?p=preview

Comment: Is the file 'angular-masonry-directive.js' loaded in your networks? Did you inspect that?

Comment: Just checked there, it's loading fine.
http://marcmurray.net/test_sites/card_site/scripts/directives/angular-masonry-directive.js

Comment: Can you create plnkr link?

Comment: Here it is! https://plnkr.co/edit/vzhUUtKtrZWxCwMITOL6?p=preview
The divs actually display in the plunker which is strange, however masonry still isn't taking effect on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined` - so the issue isn't related to the `directive` - it's because `Masonry()` doesn't exist - I think you're missing `http://masonry.desandro.com/`

This is the problem: `var masonry = scope.masonry = new Masonry(container, options);`

Comment: Wow I completely assumed the directive would have masonry packaged with it! Thanks.